# How to open the java application with database to another computer

Tags: java, jdbc

Should I do the "Embedded Database" if I want the program I created with the database to be able to access another computer?

I finally export my Java application as an executable file/application file, but my only problem is that its database needs to be always connected to the database I created. So, when I run it, It runs perfectly but I cannot access my database unless the NetBeans is running in the background. But I want it to be able to run independently without NetBeans and needing to connect to the database every time so that I can run it to my other computer. I read that I should create an embedded database so that when I try to open the file to another computer, the database is included.

Is my understanding right? I created a database using JDBC.

Comment: are you using spring boot in your app?

Comment: You have provided insufficient information in your question for to be answerable, in addition this is rather a subjective question. In any case, if your application currently requires NetBeans to run, then it sounds like you need to setup a database that is is independent of NetBeans. The rest of your question then becomes a matter of its actual deployment model and distribution (e.g. is this an in-company application ('local'/private network), global (over the internet); does data need to be shared between users or machines; etc).

Answer (score 0):

if you want to connect to your database in other computer,you'd better create your database on Server which connected to the Internet.

Comment: You may want to elaborate your answer a bit to be useful with the experience level the asker seems to have.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the type of application which you are going to develop.
If your application is a single-user standalone system then it's perfectly fine to use an embedded database. Example: Single-player game.(In here application's database is hosted within the user's machine so other users can't access those data)
But if you are developing an application which is having more than one user and those users need to share their data with others then you should go for a database like Amazon RDS which is hosted on the cloud, because then you can share those data among all the users.
(Ex: Microsoft Teams Application)

Finally, I should say yes you don't need to have NetBeans working if you select either one of those options.